# Extracting .app on Mac with QuaZip

Tags: c++, macos, qt, zip, quazip

I'm basically trying to extract a Mac application from a zip file using QuaZip. The code I'm using is:

```
QuaZip zip("file.zip");
qDebug() << zip.open(QuaZip::mdUnzip);

QuaZipFile file(&zip);
QFile out("application.app");
out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

for(bool f=zip.goToFirstFile(); f; f=zip.goToNextFile()) {
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    //same functionality as QIODevice::readData() -- data is a char*, maxSize is qint64
    char c;
    while (file.getChar(&c)) out.putChar(c);      

    file.close();
}

out.flush();
out.close();

zip.close();
```

If I try to start the extracted app, I get an error message saying I "can't open the Application, because the Classic-Environment is no longer supported." I tried to make the .app executable but it still didn't work. I don't know any other easy way to extract an application using Qt.

I extracted it with the normal archiver and the application worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with QuaZip, but it almost looks like you're trying to extract the whole archive to a single file called "application.app", which is pretty seriously wrong. Applications are actually folders, not files -- the Finder just displays the folder (which has a name ending in ".app") as if it were a single file.

If you can dig up an example of using QuaZip to extract a ZIP file, you should just be able to use that code largely unmodified (other than the __MACOSX metadata, possibly).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Worked on Linux until yet.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to just call unzip from your app using QProcess or system().

```
unzip -q <path-to-zip> -d <path-to-destionation>
```